# $.post not working cannot recieve data on action page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a password reset PHP form page that has another PHP file in action attribute of form tag. the **latter** (say `process.php`) processes the **formers**(say `reset.php`) form data to reset the password in the database now in between these two I have used a **js** file for client-side form validation and sending $.post request

in the data attribute of $.post request i inserted the $data = $("#passwordresetform :input").serializeArray();

until this point, every thing works fine when I see form data in developer tool for process.php page it shows the data as required but I have received the data in process.php using

```
mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
```

and stored all values in the associative array as

```
$data = array (
    'name' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $pass,
);
```

to return the data I have used

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

but it not returning data back e.g when I seeing preview section of developer tool it shows false for every key in returned data object i.e data

how do I solve this problem? thanks in advance.

I think the problem is really with my database connection as after I removed `mysql_real_escape_string(trim(` it worked fine so is there any other way to sanitize `$_POST` data?

but had it been a database connection problem then how come the same page retrieves data from database?

Comment: there may be jquery confliction, try jQuery instead of $

Comment: Where are you assigning values to `$username`, `$email` and `$pass`?

Comment: Also, please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: What is the response on success of ajax post request.?

Comment: i flashes the error or success messages

Answer (score 1):

**mysql_real_escape_string()** - Returns the escaped string, or **FALSE** on error.

further: A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and **FALSE** is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: i have used database connection

Comment: have you tried to remove all the stuff, like mysql_real_escape_string() and other functions like trim and whatever, that is not really needed to get any result other than false?

Comment: is it so? and you are sure you have a mysql-connection opened? try to select something from your mysql directly under your mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign values to varibales $username, $email and $pass.

```
$data = array (
    'name' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $pass,
);
```

Comment: Are you successfully connected to mysql database as mysql_real_escape_string() returns FALSE when database connected link does not exists.